# PHP Set up the time with correct day date

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on my php script to set up the date with the time. I need some help with set up the correct day date, because on my code when I have two different times `06:00` and `20:00`, it will show the time with the current day date. I find that my code have set up the date is wrong because the time I have `06:00` which it should have set up with the next day date and the time `20:00` should set up with the today date as my current time is `21:18pm` right now.

Output for `$autoresponder_date`:

```
2019-11-25 06:00
2019-11-25 20:00
```

Output for `$get_time`:

```
06:00
20:00
```

Here is the code:

```
$auto_responders = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM autoresponder WHERE campaign = ? ORDER BY id ASC');
$auto_responders->execute([$campaign]);
$auto_responders->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$auto_responders = $auto_responders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$get_time = $auto_responders['send_time'];

if ($get_time >= strtotime('00:00'))
{
    $autoresponder_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($get_time . ' +1 day'));
}
else
{
   $autoresponder_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($get_time));
}
$send_time = $autoresponder_date . ' '. date('H:i ', strtotime($get_time));
```

Can you please show me an example how I can set up the day date for the time `06:00` and `20:00` as if the time is `06:00` and my current time is before 12AM then set up to the next day date and the time is  `20:00` then it should set up the current day date before 12AM?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you specified the time zone? My first advice is using complete date and time in your code instead of date lonely

Comment: No i havent. How i can specified the time zone?

Comment: at first of your code `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Comment: @Hamid I have put the specified the time zone on the top of my code and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: specific conditions clearly like: `if($get_time >= 'today 06:00') then $autoresponder_date = 'nextday 06:00' `

Answer (score 0):

It's better using DateTime. I changed your code as below but your condition is not clear.
If you couldn't manage if...else so comment your conditions then I will update the answer.
in order convert text to DateTiem:

```
$get_time = '2019-11-25 06:00';
$get_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$get_time);
//now $get_time is an object
```

your code will be as below:

```
$auto_responders = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM autoresponder WHERE campaign = ? ORDER BY id ASC');
$auto_responders->execute([$campaign]);
$auto_responders->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$auto_responders = $auto_responders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$get_time = $auto_responders['send_time'];

$get_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i',$get_time);
if ($get_time >= new DateTime())
{
    $autoresponder_date = $get_time->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
}
else
{
   $autoresponder_date = $get_time->format('Y-m-d');
}
$send_time = $autoresponder_date . ' '. $get_time->format('H:i');
```